# How to know batch_size when fitting model with python generator?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder

I am about to train LSTM autoencoder on sequences of frames. The training data shape is (22506, 10, 256, 256, 1). Since the data is large, I store it as python generator:

```
images = []
for video in sorted(os.listdir(Config.TRAIN_PATH), key=lambda x: int(x)):
    for sequence in sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(Config.TRAIN_PATH, '0')), key=lambda x: int(x)):
        for frame in sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(Config.TRAIN_PATH, '0', sequence)), key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0])):
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(Config.TRAIN_PATH, '0', sequence, frame))
            image = cv2.resize(image, (256, 256))
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
            image = image / 256
            images.append(image)
images = np.array(images)

def seqgen(images):
    for i in range(len(images)-Config.WINDOW_SIZE):
        sequence = images[i:i+Config.WINDOW_SIZE].reshape(Config.WINDOW_SIZE, Config.H, Config.W, 1)
        yield sequence, sequence

sequences = seqgen(images)
```

keras.fit() documentation on `batch_size` argument:

```
Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. 
If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. 
Do not specify the batch_size if your data is 
in the form of datasets, generators, or 
keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).
```

So, how do I know the batch_size? I need it to calculate `steps_per_epoch` and `epochs` arguments, so I can specify it in model.fit().